# Listening on asterisk active calls from custom IOS app

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, asterisk

I am working on an mobile app to listen in on ongoing asterisk calls. Asterisk is set up to record calls, however the inbound and outgoing voices get saved to different wav files. Overcoming first obstacle was to stream wav files while they are being written to - this was achieved using Node JS, however now I need to join the mix two files together and stream them, which would be doable if the files were not written to at the same time.

First option would be to figure out how to programatically join the two while continuously checking if EOF has changed while also streaming the result. (Feels above my paygrade)

Second option would be to stream two files independently to client IOS application which would play them at the same time. If the first challenge of playing two streams simultaneously would be solved, it would require very stable connection. Therefore I don't see this as a viable option

Third possibility would be to embed softphone into the IOS app and use it as a client for ChanSpy. Would that be possible and what library can help me achieve it?

What do you guys suggest, perhaps there are more options out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about Using [Application_MixMonitor](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_MixMonitor) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build a SIP client on IOS and use ChanSpy to listen to the calls live?

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy

Comment: What library would you recommend for building a SIP client for IOS?

Comment: No idea, I know nothing about building IOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply m option to mixmon application or use sox to do the mixing.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Monitor

http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/tag/mixmonitor-sox-mixing-asterisk-script/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these 2 options don't seem to make it possible to "live" mix audio files, therefore, the call cannot be streamed in realtime.

Comment: sure.it do that after end of call. If need in call, need use sip or asterisk rtp streaming or something like that. Streaming will also have 0.5 sec delay.